# Connecting Android application with a webservice

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [About Android button event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952449/about-android-button-event)

Hi
i am developing an android application which has the following feature :

Spinner1:Showing some currency e.g:US $, Pound etc
Spiner2:Showing some currency e.g:US $, Pound etc

Three button:
Clean
Swap
Convert

anybody have any idea how i run my application using a web service?
i need code.