# Android Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Connecting Android application with a webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959641/connecting-android-application-with-a-webservice)
>   [About Android button event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952449/about-android-button-event)

Hi
I am doing android programming.
I am a newcomer in this arena. now i am doing a simple project.
i have two spinner in the screen.The two spinner is called "From" and "To".

They show the following currencies:
1.  USD (US Dollar)
2.  EUR (Euro)
3.  GBP (Great Britain Pound)
4.  AUD (Australian Dollar)
5.  CAD (Canadian Dollar)
6.  BDT (Bangladeshi Taka)
7.  INR (Indian Rupees)
8.  JPY (Japanese Yen)

There is a button in the screen called "Convert"and a text field called "result".Now when i click the convert button i want the conversion of money in the following rate:
•   1 USD=0.69881 EUR
•   1 USD=0.61095 GBP
•   1 USD=0.93188 AUD
•   1 USD=0.96680 CAD
•   1 USD=44.72 INR
•   1 USD= 73.14 BDT
•   1 USD=80.55 JPY
The result will be shown in the "result" text field.Can any body help me with code?